# Context-aware commands?

Tags: macros

I used command `\important` throughout the document to mark the important parts of the text, and although it was initially bold and red, in the end I chose to style it simply as bold.

However, the same command `\important` was used in margin notes and I'd like to keep the text red in margin notes.

How can I (re)define the command so that it behaves differently in regular text (bold) and in margin notes (bold and red)? In CSS, for example, what I'm trying to do would be accomplished like the following:

```
.important { font-weight: bold; }
.margin-note .important { color: red; }
```

Comment: You should add a hook to `\marginpar` (there's none presently) that sets a new conditional `\ifmarginpar` and then define `\important` using it.

Comment: Or can you patch the command using something like **etoolbox**?

Comment: A little bit more information or a working document would be helpful

Comment: Or just use a dirty little hack.  How can you tell if you're in a margin?  The line width is small!  So you can just do "if \linewidth == \marginparwidth, the use red".  Or whatever the right incantation is for margin note vs margin par is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

LaTeX does not define contexts like CSS does. There are however some hooks that can be exploited in a similar way. For `\marginpar` there's `\@marginparreset` that's executed when the text for a margin note is going to start.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{etoolbox} % for convenience

\makeatletter
% patch \@marginparreset so it sets a conditional to true
% (it is executed when TeX has started a box, so it's local)
\apptocmd{\@marginparreset}{\toggletrue{marginpar}}{}{}
\newtoggle{marginpar}
\makeatother

% conditional commands should be robust
\newrobustcmd{\important}[1]{%
  \textcolor{\iftoggle{marginpar}{red}{blue}}{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\important{This is important}\marginpar{\important{This is too}}

\important{This is important}\marginpar{\important{This is too}}

\end{document}
```

[image]